# bitcond and bitcoin-Qt system configuration and bandwidth requirements

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, linux, bandwidth

What is the best operating system configuration for a computer to run (bitcoind or bitcoin-Qt) and (BFGminer or CGMiner) under Linux, assuming that it will be connected to a 3 Terrahash mining rig on one side and the internet on the other side?

What packages, at minimum, must be installed?

How much bandwidth will I need using the Stratum protocol and how much using the GetBlockTemplate protocol?

EDIT TO ADD:

What I mean by "best configuration" is the minimum configuration that provides the necessary functionality.

I'm willing to bet that 90 percent of what's in a desktop Linux distribution is not needed in this application.

Obviously, a kernel and a shell will be needed.  What else?

Comment: "Best" all depends on how you're measuring. Are you looking for smallest? cheapest? lowest power consumption? fastest? coolest? quietest?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be mining by yourself, or in a pool? If you are mining in a pool, you won't need bitcoind or bitcoin-QT running, and you can use a Raspberry PI to run CGMiner. Raspberry PI is very easy to set up, fast and requires much less oversight/administration as compared to a consumer grade laptop/computer.

Answer (score -1):

For dependenices the minumum i was able to get away with was

```
libdb4.8-dev
libdb4.8++-dev
libminiupnpc-dev
libqt4-dev
libprotobuf-dev
protobuf-compiler
apt-get install libqrencode-dev
```

and make sure you have enough room for validation i had the many errors coming up for not dedicating enough. Personally when it comes to bandwidth I needed way more than 14 Mbps.

Comment: Your forgetting dependencies like build-essential